# SQL Server 2019 update CU8 to CU9 - lots of messages in errorlog file... DBID: [9] No DEK update for File Id [4] while existing DEK is null

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

This is `SQL Server 2019 CU9 Developer edition` on my 16GB laptop:
I updated from CU8 to CU9:
I ran checkDB on all of my DBs no issues.

Lots of these messages in my SQL Server Log file viewer:

> DBID: [9] No DEK update for File Id: [4] while existing DEK is null
> DBID: [9] File Header for File Id:[4] was read with state = 0 Refresh
> DEK for DBID: [9] File ID: [4] - Copying encryption state DBID: [9] No
> DEK update for File Id: [3] while existing DEK is null DBID: [9] File
> Header for File Id:[3] was read with state = 0 Refresh DEK for DBID:
> [9] File ID: [3] - Copying encryption state blah blah.. DBID: [2] No
> DEK update for File Id: [6] while existing DEK is null DBID: [2] File
> Header for File Id:[6] was read with state = 0 Refresh DEK for DBID:
> [2] File ID: [6] - Copying encryption state

I don't even have a DBID of 9?

```
select * from master.dbo.sysdatabases

name    dbid sid mode status status2 crdate reserved category cmptlevel filename version
master  1 0x01 0 65544 1090520064 2003-04-08 09:13:36.390 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 0 140 C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf 904
tempdb  2 0x01 0 65544 1090520064 2021-02-18 16:24:25.070 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 0 150 C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\tempdb.mdf 904
model   3 0x01 0 65536 1090519040 2003-04-08 09:13:36.390 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 0 150 C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\model.mdf 904
msdb    4 0x01 0 65544 1627390976 2017-08-22 19:39:22.887 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 0 150 C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\MSDBData.mdf 904
ETRACKSystem74_SQL 5  0x010500000000000515000000E187A991DF25ABE0CE633A3C72040000 0 16 553648128 2018-11-08 21:47:31.427 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 0 140 C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\ETRACKSystem74_SQL_Data.mdf 904
TEST2   6 0x010500000000000515000000E187A991DF25ABE0CE633A3C72040000 0 16 553648128 2019-05-22 11:02:08.600 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 0 140 C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\TEST2_Data.mdf 904
TEST3   7 0x010500000000000515000000E187A991DF25ABE0CE633A3C72040000 0 16 553648128 2019-05-22 11:05:49.800 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 0 140 C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\TEST3_Data.mdf 904
FortisTKCSDB 8 0x010500000000000515000000E187A991DF25ABE0CE633A3C72040000 0 65544 553648128 2020-04-10 08:42:23.933 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 0 120 C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\FortisTKCSDB.mdf 904
```

Comment: They also generate the message again in the SQL messages log when you run DBCC checkdb against the user DBs.   CheckDB finds no issues from SSMS.

Comment: The DEK messages look to be introduced in CU9 and are informational, not a problem. I can't find this documented, though. Rather than the deprecated `dbo.sysdatabases` view, try `sys.databases` and `sys.master_files`.

Comment: These messages are informational can be safely ignored, but their appearance was unexpected.  The SQL Server team is aware of this issue and is looking into a fix that suppresses the messages.

Comment: Thank You!   for your feedback